# i try to build and run a apache ignite example in binary package on intelij idea IDE. there are so many errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ignite

I try to build and run a apache ignite example in binary package on Intelij idea IDE. When I run example, there are so many errors. please any one can help me to run a simple example ?
I have installed java python and maven on my laptop. I am very new to apache ignite and java. i follow to run example according to the instruction in official grid gain website(Ignite Quick Start Guide for Java) but still I couldn't run a even a example. please help me to find what is the correct way to do this?

This image is IDE with Errors:

[image: This image is IDE with Errors]

Comment: It looks like Windows Defender is blocking your IDE from downloading the dependencies. You need to unblock it then attempt to download dependencies again

Comment: @caladeve: I don't think that's what that popup means. The warning on the lower right is only about performance. Meaning that Windows defender monitoring the the project directory can slow down builds, but shouldn't build them.

Comment: thanks your corporation. I resolve the impact of defender according to the instruction. now this popup window doesn't display. but still there are errors.

Comment: When I try to run it, IDEA complains about some kind of K8S example, but once I remove that file, it builds and runs all right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is [Safe Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-security.html#gradle_maven_projects). IDEA does not trust the build scripts (Maven configuration) of this project as a safety precaution.

This means it will not download the appropriate dependencies and apply the plugins specified therein, effectively not building the project.

If you trust the project and/or have verified that there's nothing malicious in the build script or its plugins, then you can disable safe mode by clicking "Trust project ..." in the banner on top of the editor window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I open the project as trusted project. But there are so many errors available. I used to Intelij Idea IDE to build and run this example project. I think  , i have some mistakes somewhere. But i can't it guess with my poor knowledge about ignite and java. But since this very essential part of my university project, i want to learn. If any one can help to start this agian from beginning , it is very large help to me.